# What am I doing wrong when trying to override a template?

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I am building an application using Sonata Page Bundle. I noticed that the toggle for enabling and disabling content blocks does not do anything.

There is an [open pull request](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataPageBundle/issues/836) for this issue, but for the moment, I just want to make the enable/disable button go away. So I do the following per [this page](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/templating/overriding.html):

```
cp ./vendor/sonata-project/page-bundle/Resources/views/BlockAdmin/compose_preview.html.twig app/Resources/SonataPageBundle/views/BlockAdmin/compose_preview.html
```

... and start editing my new clone of the template.

But the new template does not appear to override the vendor template. I have tried clearing the cache to no avail. What step am I missing to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Well that was simple. I had accidentally cloned into `compose_preview.html` rather than `compose_preview.html.twig`

I added `.twig` to the end of my template name and my problem was solved.